# Inconsistent ggplot subgroup order

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: See the plot here]

I'm having trouble with a tiny detail here in the ggplot. As you can see, the first subgroup (8th) has blue bar before the red bar, while the others have the other way around... I can't figure out a way to get them to be consistent. Any thoughts?

Here is my code:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(reshape2)

grade <- factor(c("8th","10th","12th"), levels = c("8th","10th","12th"))
alc.py <- c("37", "38", "41")
alcpy.st <- c("23", "42", "58" )
alcohol.py <- data.frame(grade, alc.py, alcpy.st)
alcohol.py <- melt(alcohol.py, id.vars = "grade")


ggplot(alcohol.py, aes(x=grade, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab("Past Year Alchol Use") +
  ylab("Percentage of use (%)")
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Please fix your code.

Comment: Right, you need to load the packages first

Comment: Still not reproducible. I got this error message: `Error in data.frame(grade, alc.py, alcpy.st) : object 'grade' not found`.

Comment: Oops, forgot a line. Should be fine now

Comment: Just add anither aesthetic, `ggplot(alcohol.py, aes(x=grade, y=value, fill=variable, group=variable))`. `group` by `variable`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another aesthetic, group by `variable`.

```
ggplot(alcohol.py, aes(x=grade, y=value, fill=variable, group=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab("Past Year Alcohol Use") +
  ylab("Percentage of use (%)")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot!